# python list of tuples to list of dicts for use by csv.dictwriter

Tags: python, dictionary

i have this scenario

```
x=['a','b','c']   #Header
y=[(1,2,3),(4,5,6)]   #data
```

I need to create below structure

```
[{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}, {'a':4, 'b':5, 'c':6}]
```

Any better way of doing this(like a python expert)

```
rows=[]
for row in range(0,len(y)):
    rec={}
    for col in range(0, len(x)):
        rec[x[col]]=y[row][col]
    rows.append(rec)    
print(rows)
```

above code will give the desired result, but i am looking for a one liner solution some thing like below

```
rows=list( ( {x[col]:y[row][col]} for row in range(0,len(y)) for col in range(0, len(x)) ) )
```

output:

```
[{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 3}, {'a': 4}, {'b': 5}, {'c': 6}]
```

but this gives list as individual dict's rather than a combined dict. Any ideas???

Answer (score 3):

You could write a generator that iterates over data. Then for each item in data use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to generate iterable of `(header, value)` tuples that you pass to [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict):

```
>>> x = ['a','b','c']
>>> y = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6)]
>>> gen = (dict(zip(x, z)) for z in y)
>>> list(gen)
[{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}, {'a': 4, 'c': 6, 'b': 5}]
```

**Update** The example above uses *generator expression* instead of `list` since the code writing CSV would only need one row at a time. Generating the full list would require much more memory with no benefit.

Comment: why the generator?  a list comprehension does what's asked for: `[dict(zip(x,v)) for v in y]`

Comment: i'm sure the generator is in case OP has a large dataset and would like to optimize for memory efficiency. otherwise there's no issue

Comment: @f5r5e5d Added reasoning for generator expression to answer

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect.